# proc_open called only one time in foreach loop

Tags: php, shell, exec, proc, proc-open

```
class CommandExecuter {

const EXEC_FAILED = "EXEC_FAILED";

public function execute($cmd, $sleep, $descriptors, $progressCallback, $progressCallbackParams, $showProgress = false, $callbackTurns = 0) {

    log_out("INFO", basename(__FILE__), "Executing: $cmd");

    // Start execution of $cmd
    if (!($process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptors, $pipes)) || !is_resource($process)) {

        throw new CTException("Unable to execute command:\n$cmd\n", self::EXEC_FAILED);
    }

    // Set the pipes as non-blocking
    if (isset($descriptors[1]) && $descriptors[1]) {

        stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], FALSE);
    }
    if (isset($descriptors[2]) && $descriptors[2]) {

        stream_set_blocking($pipes[2], FALSE);
    }
    if ($callbackTurns) {
        $i = 0;
    }
    // Used to store all output
    $allOut = "";
    $allOutErr = "";

    // Check process status at every turn
    $procStatus = proc_get_status($process);
    while ($procStatus['running']) {

        // Read prog output
        if (isset($descriptors[1]) && $descriptors[1]) {

            $out = fread($pipes[1], 8192);
            $allOut .= $out;
        }

        // Read prog errors
        if (isset($descriptors[2]) && $descriptors[2]) {

            $outErr = fread($pipes[2], 8192);
            $allOutErr .= $outErr;
        }

        // If callback only after N turns
        if ($callbackTurns) {
            if ($i == $callbackTurns) {
                if ($showProgress) {
                    echo ".\n";
                }

                // Call user provided callback.
                // Callback should be an array as per doc here: 
                // http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php
                // Type 3: Object method call
                if (isset($progressCallback) && $progressCallback) {

                    call_user_func($progressCallback, $progressCallbackParams, $allOut, $allOutErr);
                }

                $i = 0;
            }
        } else {

            // Call user provided callback.
            // Callback should be an array as per doc here: 
            // http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php
            // Type 3: Object method call
            if (isset($progressCallback) && $progressCallback) {

                call_user_func($progressCallback, $progressCallbackParams, $allOut, $allOutErr);
            }
        }

        // Get latest status
        $procStatus = proc_get_status($process);

        if ($showProgress) {

            echo ".";
            flush();
        }

        if ($callbackTurns) {

            $i++;
        }

        sleep($sleep);
    }

    if ($showProgress) {
        echo "\n";
    }

    // Process is over
    proc_close($process);

    return array('out' => $allOut, 'outErr' => $allOutErr);
  }

}
```

following scenario: when i put the executer command into an foreach loop the executer gets only one time called and the rest of the foreach loop are dead or hangs forever.

So what is wrong ?

Here is the call...

```
$out = $this->executer->execute('some call', 1, array(2 => array("pipe", "w")), false, false, false, 1);
```

Regards Sascha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it the class is written without errors.
I solved it in the programm.
On the cli have forgotten the -y force overwrite parameter.

Thanks Sascha